Oxente! vs Oxe!
I kind of knew already about the Nordeste word "Oxe!" which is very cute. Now in Pernambuco I have seen various tourist souvenirs having written "Oxente" on them.
These two words are the same, right? So "Oxe" is an abbreviation of "Oxente".
When do people use the longer form "Oxente"?

Oxente é redução de «ó gente», com sotaque nordestino.

Yes, they're the same, "oxente" derives from the agglutination of the expression "ó gentes" (an exclamation, comparable with "c'mon guys" or "hey guys"), and "oxe" is the reduced form of "oxente".
The only reason I can imagine for preferring one over the other is style or personal preference.

I don't think it takes an s. Gente is already plural....:)

@Lambie I know, but that's given in the Houaiss and Dicio. According to Priberam "gentes" (pl.) can be also used as an interjection.

Priberam under oxente: Origem etimológica:redução de ó gente. [Brasil: Nordeste, Popular] Exprime estranheza, indagação ou surpresa. = OXE
"oxente", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2024, https://dicionario.priberam.org/oxente.
"oxente", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2024, https://dicionario.priberam.org/oxente.

@Lambie, Sim, eu vi, é o link do comentário do Jorge. Mas são dois dicionários contra um a favor do plural. ;-)

@Lambie E tem, entre outras, essa obra do Artur de Azevedo, usando "gentes" em três pontos diferentes, por exemplo "Emília - Ó gentes! Eu não sou santa, seu Alberto." E também a peça do Martins Pena, "Os dois ou o inglês maquinista". Hoje em dia penso que não se falaria, mas no passado claramente era usado.

Not in Brazil. because it says clearly that oxente without s = [Brasil: Nordeste, Popular] Exprime estranheza, indagação ou surpresa.

@Lambie Yes, no source has "oxentes", but apparently the original expression was "ó gentes", had the "s". Artur de Azevedo was Brazilian so, even if the "ó gentes" was first used in Portugal, it was also known in Brazil in the past.

@stafusa   I've never heard any nordestino say "oxentes".  As for "gentes", it's not exactly the plural of "gente".  See Bandeira's "Quando a indesejada das gentes chegar..."

@Centaurus Yeah, I've never heard either, not did find anything relevant online. I guess the people who started to agglutinate into "oxente" didn't use "ó gentes" with "s".
